# Eclipse won't forget about a previous mistake

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm learning c++ and Im using Eclipse to practice. I mispelled one of the libraries I've used, but now after I deleted that line completely, Eclipse won't forgive me and still bug me about the problem. Any help how to solve it?
[image: The problem]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: click on the stale error and press delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply save the file i believe that's your problem. if it doesn't work restart eclipse may help too! eclipse has some bugs like this its normal.